# How to update events when clicking prev and next in full calendar using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, events, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar with events generated from a json file. What i want to do is to show list of events in a month when user clicks next or prev button using full calendar plugin. I tried to achieve but when i click next and prev button it doesn't shows the events. 
For example in the month of august , i have some four events which will be displayed in a div when i click a arrow at the bottom of the calendar. If i click next , it should not display any events as i don't have any events in the next month. but when i go to the month of jan , 2015 , it should show one event because i have binded one event in the month of january. but it displays the previous month events as well as current month events. how to solve this problem.

html

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
<i class="fa fa-shield fa-2x"></i>
<div id="upcoming">
    <div class="lines">
        <div id="hidden"></div>
```

js :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#upcoming').hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "kupArj.json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

            eventData = data;
            eventDataFn(eventData);
            eventupdateFn(eventData);
            $('#calendar').on('click', '.fc-button-next',function(){
                $('#upcoming').hide();
            formater(data);

    });

        }
    });
$('.fa-2x').click(function(){
     $('#upcoming').toggle("slow");    
});

    function  formater(eventData)
    {
    var s = $('h2').html();
    console.log(s)
    var format1 = new moment(s);
    var start1 = format1.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    var splitStart1 = start1.split('/');
    var month = splitStart1[1];
    var years = splitStart1[2];
    for (var i = 0; i < eventData.length; i++) {
    var s1 = eventData[i].start;
    var dd = new moment(s1);
    var start = dd.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    var splitStart = start.split('/');
    console.log(month,splitStart[1]);
    if (month == splitStart[1]) {
      $('#upcoming').append(eventData[i].title+'<br>'+eventData[i].msg+'<br>'+'<div class="lines">')
    } else {
        console.log(eventData);
    }
    }
} 

    /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {



        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
    });


    /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function eventDataFn(eventData) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.popover({
                    title: event.title,
                    placement: 'auto',
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    animation:'true',
                    content: event.msg
                });
                $('body').on('click', function(e) {
                    if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
                        element.popover('hide');
                });
            },
            events: eventData
        });

    }
    });
    function eventupdateFn(eventData) {
        var date = new Date();
        for (i = 0; i < eventData.length; i++) {
            var s = eventData[i].start;
            var dd = new moment(s);
            var start = dd.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
            var mon = date.getMonth() + 1 ;
            var year = dd.year();
            var splitStart = start.split('/');
            var day = date.getDate();
            if (mon == splitStart[1]) {
                $('#upcoming').append(eventData[i].title+'<br>'+eventData[i].msg+'<br>'+'<div class="lines">')    
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("fail");
            }
        }
    }
```